# How to recover corrupted Windows XP installation?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, linux-mint

I have a Netbook without a CD rom which has been running Windows XP.

I decided to install Linux on it to run a dual setup, however that somehow corrupted my Windows installation, probably because of when Linux Mint created its partition, perhaps it overwrote some data from Win XP.

I was previously getting an error for a missing file, which I downloaded and put into my system32 folder. Now when I boot windows, it just gets stuck on 'mup.sys' file and then it reboots. I think this is because of missing windows files, and if I could just restore windows xp from a boot disk, that would fix it.

Since I don't have a CD rom, I have to use a USB to create a windows XP bootdisk. So far I'm not having any luck with that. All the tools for building a Windows boot disk seem to be Windows only, and I can't seem to be able to run them on Wine.

Any ideas how to fix this situation?

Comment: You can try reading the Windows XP iso (if you have it ) with a zip/iso program and get the mup.sys file (it would have to be uncompressed/extracted first).